# When value of column A are similar, then it will sum the column b depending on column A by creating another new table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA Excel so I just figured out the code to sort the number ascending for column A. Next, I want to sum up the (value) of column B if the Column A (bill) are same. I use VBA because I want it to automate the moment I press command button.

```
   lrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lrow

    If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then


         'copy qty order of 2nd row. then plus with previous qty order . 
              store in the previous order the Result.
          result = Cells(i, 3) + Cells(i + 1, 3)

          Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Copy
          erow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
          Worksheets(1).Paste Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(erow + 1, 1)

          Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Copy
          Worksheets(1).Paste Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(erow + 1, 2)


    Else
         result = Cells(i, 3).Value
         Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Copy
         erow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         Worksheets(1).Paste Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(erow + 1, 1)
         Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Copy
         Worksheets(1).Paste Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(erow + 1, 2)

    End If
  Next i

  Application.CutCopyMode = False

         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
```

I expect the output will appear a in new worksheet 2.

(Worksheet 1)

```
bill    value                     
200     3213    
200     123    
200     3791
200     34    
200     45    
200     56    
200     76    
201     123    
201     10993    
201     5435    
202     2432    
202     135    
202     5646 
202     76776
```

(Worksheet 2)

```
bill    value   
200     7338    
201     16551   
202     84989
```

Comment: I think you'd better should learn how PivotTables work. They will do all that work for you in a very simple way. The results are dinamic and with a simple refresh you will process all source data very quickly.

Comment: i need this thing to run automatically using a button..

Comment: Yes and this is totally possible with PivotTables, just need to create the PivotTable linked with the potential source for your data and add a button that makes the PivotTable.Refresh. Much easier and lower risk of failure that learning VBA.